# How to set local host in 127.0.0.1

Tags: laravel, xampp

There’s something I don’t understand about my laravel project. I’m using xampp. When I write https://localhost in my browser, it takes me to my web page, but if instead of writing localhost I write https://127.0.0.1 it takes me to laravel dashboard and not my web page. I don’t know why that happens. Does anyone know why it happens? Thank you.

Comment: try `http://127.0.0.1/yourProjectFolderName/public`

Comment: an IP can correspond to multiple hosts so when you configure XAMPP you need to be explicit with your host configuration

Comment: @apokryfos and if I want my laravel page to be in 127.0.0.1 what do I have to do? Modifying the .env file?

Comment: Check your XAMPP site configuration. You should have a default site and one for localhost. Make sure both of these serve the same site.

Comment: @apokryfos I checked my .env file and changed it. Now i t works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the [`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/host) that the browser sends. When you go to `http://localhost`, it'll send:

```
Host: localhost
```

but when you go to `http://127.0.0.1`, it'll send:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

The server uses the `Host` header to figure out what content to reply with, since the same server can be serving multiple websites with different domains and different document roots.

Apparently your server (probably via your Laravel configuration in your specific case) is set up to handle a host called `localhost`, but not one called `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand it. And now, if a I want my laravel page to be shown when the url is https://127.0.0.1, what do I have to do?

Comment: @lewis04 - Why would you want to:? But I'm afraid I can't answer that new question, I don't do Laravel config.